# I have a problem with Woocommerce. the cart page and checkout are on one page, namely the checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with Woocommerce.
the cart page and checkout are on one page, namely the checkout page.
I want when the update qty is for example 2 qty, then the billing form will be double input. for example the form above for me and the form below for my wife. like name, email, phone.
Please help.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please attach relevant images / explanation and expected behaviour to clear your question among users.

Comment: Also you can add code if you changed something on the page. This helps us too.